# Preview is different from the post

Tags: bug, preview

https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/139329/114966

Seems like lists and equations are not friendly with each other.

Preview: [image] Result: [image]

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have fixed it, now all the indentations are in line and they all say `N.` rather than `N)`:

---

1. \begin{align}
   v_1 + v_2 + v_3 \qquad = 1\\
   \qquad v_2 + v_3 + v_4 = 1\\
   v_1 \qquad  + v_3 + v_4 = 1\\
   v_1 + v_2 \qquad + v_4 = 1\\
   \end{align}
   It's easy to check that $v_1=v_2=v_3=v_4=\frac 13$ is the unique solution.
2. Consider $v_5 + v_6 + v_7 + v_8 + 0 \cdot v_9 = 1$ and, similarly to the above case, all cyclic shifts of $(v_5, \ldots, v_9)$. Again, the unique solution is $v_5 = v_6 = v_7 = v_8 = v_9 = \frac 14$.
3. The last equation is
   $$v_1 + v_2 \qquad + v_5 \qquad + v_{10} = 1$$
   Then $v_{10} = 1 - 2 \cdot \frac 13 - \frac 14 = \frac 1 {12}$.

---

Comment: My concern is not that the post doesn't look great. The concern is that the preview (when you edit the post) doesn't look the same as the post (and this sounds like a bug).

Comment: The preview matches here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDKoG.png. I'm not sure if this is such a major bug, it may have been a consequence of incorrect use of the numerical bulletting system, which requires proper spacing.